# Is there a good demonstration of bidirectional type checking with strict Prop?

Tags: implementation, prop

I've seen elaboration-zoo, pi-forall, Mini-TT, etc., all kinds of demonstrations of dependent type elaboration. However, none of them support `Prop`.

I am interested in the following specific type checking problem about `Prop`.
I have read somewhere in TaPL saying that for `Prop`, one cannot simply eliminate it to `Type`. I understand semantically why, but I am having trouble finding an elegant way to algorithmize it. I (together with some friends) came up with the following naive attempts, all seem stupid and ugly:

- Add a boolean parameter to `inherit`/`synthesize`, the two directions of type checking, representing whether we are allowed to eliminate from `Prop` here in the term. We also add it to the patterns' type checker.
- Everywhere I see an elimination from a proposition, I check the context type and make sure it's also a proposition. We do the same for patterns.

I think both seem very inefficient. Is there some code examples I can look at? I conjecture that there must be some clever ways...

Comment: What kind of language are you looking at? I guess Agda-style clausal definitions? If you work with eliminators/pattern-matching, it's easy: decide in advance which inductive types are allowed to be eliminated in which universes (ie what is usually called subsingleton elimination), and when you encounter an eliminator/match, infer the universe of the return predicate, and check that it is allowed for the type you are eliminating/matching on.

Comment: @MevenLennon-Bertrand yes Agda style